# last character from user input string is not correct

Tags: string, rust, char

I am very new to Rust and I am trying to get the last value of the string from the user input. I tried implementing it but it does not give the expected output

```rust
    println!("Please input temp (ex: 60F): ");
    let mut temp = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut temp)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    println!("{temp}");
    let unit = temp.chars().last().unwrap();
    println!("unit: {}", unit);
```

would appreciate any help provided!

I tried multiple solutions from stackoverflow and reddit but it did not work as well.

expected output of the machine should look something like:

```
> Please input temp (ex: 60F): 
60f
unit: f
```

but the output I got was:

```
> Please input temp (ex: 60F): 
60f
unit:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string contains the `\n` inputted by the user. try this

```
let unit = temp.trim().chars().last().unwrap();
```

Comment: Thank you so much ursus! I also just discovered that my question is a duplicate question